# Intl.DateTimeFormat causes TypeScript error certain options

Tags: typescript, datetime-format

I have the following code that works perfectly:

```
const option = {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    weekday: 'long',
}

const myDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de', {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    weekday: 'long',
}).format(date)

const myDateTest2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de', option as any).format(date)
```

This means I get a date if I pass the object directly into the constructor.
It also works if I define the options first and then use `any`.

But this is throwing a TypeScript error:

```
const myDateTest = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de', option).format(date)
```

as follows:

```
Argument of type '{ year: string; month: string; day: string; weekday: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
  Types of property 'weekday' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"short" | "long" | "narrow"'.ts(2345)
```

Why is this?

I tried multiple TS configurations, but none of them solve the issue.

Here is what I have now:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./.tmp/build/",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "ES2020.Intl",
      "dom"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
```

TypeScript version is "typescript": "^4.8.4",

Comment: You need `as const` after your `options`.  `const option = { year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "numeric", weekday: "long" } as const`.  It's nothing specific to `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.  This is a general problem any time that you are creating a variable with `string` values and you need the string(s) to have a more specific literal type.

Comment: Alternatively, you can assign the type that you need to your `option` object. `const option: DateTimeFormatOptions = { year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "numeric", weekday: "long" }`

Comment: @ghybs, your answer was somehow deleted.

Comment: One addition shortcoming: The options are passed as a parameter into a function. If I try to convert the parameter to a const, I am getting this: `A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.`

Comment: @LindaPaiste Please make your comments an answer! ;-)

Comment: @RalphSpandl do you mean you want to do `format(option as const)`?

Comment: Still not solving it.

I have something like this:

```
test: (settings: IDateFormatSettings): string => {
        const { date, lang, dateFormat } = settings
        const localeStringFormat = () => new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
            lang || 'en-US',
            dateFormat as const
        )
            .format(date)

        return localeStringFormat();
    },
```

whereby dateFormat has the same types as in the INTL specs.

Comment: I was not saying that was what to do. See the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#caveats-1): "_One thing to note is that `const` assertions can only be applied immediately on simple literal expressions._"

Comment: Yup, the `as const` needs to be applied when you create the variable, rather than when you use it.

Answer (score 9):

#### Problem: Variable has too broad of a type

What you are experiencing here is a common problem when dealing with functions that require [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) in their arguments.  It's nothing specific to `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.  You can read the docs on [Literal Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference) for more info.

Let's take a look at what your error is telling you:

> Argument of type '{ year: string; month: string; day: string; weekday: string; }'  is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
>
> Types of property 'weekday' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"short" | "long" | "narrow"'.ts(2345)

The type of your `option.weekday` is inferred as `string`.  This is not specific enough for the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` constructor, which only allows three possible string literal values: `"short" | "long" | "narrow"`.

The *value* of your `option` variable is fine.  But TypeScript only looks at *types*, not values.

When you write your assignment statement like this:

```
const option = {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    weekday: "long",
}
```

TypeScript infers the type as:

```
const option: {
    year: string;
    month: string;
    day: string;
    weekday: string;
}
```

We need to create your variable in a way that will give it a narrower type.

#### Solution 1: Declare the type

We know from your error that the type which your `option` variable needs to fit is `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions`.  We can use that type when you create the `option` variable.

```
const option: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    weekday: "long",
}
```

TypeScript will check each of the properties of your object to make sure that they are assignable to the constraints of the `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions` type.

If you provide an invalid value, like this:

```
const option: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
    weekday: "numeric",
}
```

You'll see a red underline on the `weekday` property.  I prefer this approach for that reason -- it is easier to see exactly where the problems are.  For `weekday: "numeric"` your error message would be:

> Type '"numeric"' is not assignable to type '"long" | "short" | "narrow" | undefined'

#### Solution 2: `as const`

You can change the way that TypeScript infers the type by using an `as const` statement when you create your variable.  This tells TypeScript to treat all properties of your object as their literal types ([explained here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-inference)).

```
const option = {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "short",
    day: "numeric",
    weekday: "long",
} as const;
```

TypeScript infers the type as:

```
const option: {
    readonly year: "numeric";
    readonly month: "short";
    readonly day: "numeric";
    readonly weekday: "long";
}
```

Each property has a string literal type like `"long"` rather than just `string`.

Assuming that your values are valid, these literal types will be assignable to the broader `Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions` type.  For example, `"long"` is assignable to the union type `'"short" | "long" | "narrow"'` on the `weekday` property.